# FIZZ BUZZ -challenge program with adjustable intervals

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge, fizzbuzz

This is again a solution to the [codeEval challenge #1](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/1/). It was accepted by codeEval, but please let me know if I can improve it anyway somehow?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>

struct input_rec{
    int first;
    int second;
    int last;
};

void parseRecord( std::string &record, input_rec& rec )
{
    int first  = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int last   = 0;
    bool good  = 0;

    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end =  record.find_first_of(" ");
    first = std::atoi(record.substr(start,end-start).c_str());
    if( ( 1 <= first ) && ( first <= 20 ) )
    {
        good = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    start = end + 1;
    end = record.find_first_of( " ", start );
    second = std::atoi( record.substr( start, end-start ).c_str() );
    if( good && ( ( 1 <= second ) && ( second <= 20 ) ) )
    {
         good=1;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    start = end + 1;
    last = std::atoi( record.substr( start, std::string::npos ).c_str() );
    if( good && ( (21 <= last ) && ( second <= 200 ) ) )
    {
        good=1;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    if(good)
    {
        rec.first=first;
        rec.second=second;
        rec.last=last;
    }
}
void readInputFile( std::string fileName, std::vector< input_rec > & rec )
{

    //std::cout<<"readInputFile: filename:"<< filename<<std::endl;
    std::ifstream infile( fileName );

    std::string record;
    input_rec temp;
    while( std::getline( infile, record ) )
    {

        parseRecord( record, temp );
        rec.emplace_back( temp );
    }
}
void checkfuzzbuzz( input_rec& rec )
{ 
    int x     = 1;
    int flag1 = 0;
    int flag2 = 0;

    while( x < rec.last )
    {
        if( ( x % rec.first ) == 0)
        {
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        if ( ( x % rec.second ) == 0 )
        {
            flag2 = 1;
        }

        if( ( flag1 + flag2 ) == 2 )
        {
            std::cout << "FB" << " ";           
        }
        else if( flag1 == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "F" << " ";
        }   
        else if( flag2 == 1 )
        {
            std::cout << "B" << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        flag1 = 0;
        flag2 = 0;
        ++x;
    }
    if( x == rec.last )
    {
        if( ( x % rec.first ) == 0 )
        {
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        if ( ( x % rec.second ) == 0 )
        {
            flag2 = 1;
        }

        if( ( flag1 + flag2 ) == 2 )
        {
            std::cout << "FB";           
        }
        else if( flag1 == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "F";
        }   
        else if( flag2 == 1 )
        {
            std::cout << "B";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        flag1 = 0;
        flag2 = 0;
        ++x;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "usage: fuuzbuzz fuuzbuzz.txt" << "\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    std::vector< input_rec > input;
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ], input );    
    for( auto &x : input)
    {
       checkfuzzbuzz(x);
    }
   auto end      = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
   auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
   std::cout<< duration.count() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort your includes.

Your `input_rec` has poor names. Something like `fizz`, `buzz` and `length` would be better. If you don't want to give it better names, just use a `tuple`.

`parseRecord` takes a line and tries to fill a record. It would be more senible to just `return` a record (out-parameters are largely a bad idea for small types). This does mean you actually need to handle the early-return cases. For the moment, I'll just return `{0, 0, 0}` - this is at least better than the old arbitrary-data return value. The input should probably be taken by `const &`.

The constraints

> - The number of test cases ≤ 20
> - "X" is in range [1, 20]
> - "Y" is in range [1, 20]
> - "N" is in range [21, 100]

should *not* be part of your code. They only serve to make it less general.

This gets us to

```
input_rec parseRecord( std::string const &record )
{
    int fizz = 0;
    int buzz = 0;
    int length = 0;

    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end =  record.find_first_of(" ");
    fizz = std::atoi(record.substr(start,end-start).c_str());

    start = end + 1;
    end = record.find_first_of( " ", start );
    buzz = std::atoi( record.substr( start, end-start ).c_str() );

    start = end + 1;
    length = std::atoi( record.substr( start, std::string::npos ).c_str() );

    return {fizz, buzz, length};
}
```

The next thing to do is initialize late:

```
input_rec parseRecord( std::string const &record )
{
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end =  record.find_first_of(" ");
    int fizz = std::atoi(record.substr(start,end-start).c_str());

    start = end + 1;
    end = record.find_first_of( " ", start );
    int buzz = std::atoi( record.substr( start, end-start ).c_str() );

    start = end + 1;
    int length = std::atoi( record.substr( start, std::string::npos ).c_str() );

    return {fizz, buzz, length};
}
```

This is much simpler with an `istringstream`:

```
#include<sstream>

input_rec parseRecord( std::string const &record )
{
    std::istringstream stream(record);

    int fizz, buzz, length;
    stream >> fizz >> buzz >> length;
    return {fizz, buzz, length};
}
```

Your `readInputFile` isn't needed - one can interleave reading and writing. Letting `checkfuzzbuzz` take its argument by value, this is just:

```
std::ifstream infile( argv[ 1 ] );

std::string record;
while( std::getline( infile, record ) )
{
    checkfuzzbuzz(parseRecord( record ));
}
```

Your `exit( 0 );` in `main` can jus be `return;`, although you probably want `return 1;`.

`checkfuzzbuzz` has a typo. Further, the whole flag setting things is meaningless overhead. Just do

```
void checkfizzbuzz( input_rec rec )
{ 
    int x = 1;
    while( x < rec.length )
    {
        if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0 && ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 ) {
            std::cout << "FB" << " ";           
        }
        else if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "F" << " ";
        }
        else if ( ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "B" << " ";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        ++x;
    }
    if( x == rec.length )
    {
        if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0 && ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 ) {
            std::cout << "FB";           
        }
        else if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "F";
        }
        else if ( ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "B";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << x;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Further, you can combine the two to do

```
void checkfizzbuzz( input_rec rec )
{ 
    for( int x = 1; x <= rec.length; ++x )
    {
        if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0 && ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 ) {
            std::cout << "FB";           
        }
        else if( ( x % rec.fizz ) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "F";
        }
        else if ( ( x % rec.buzz ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "B";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << x;
        }

        if( x < rec.length ) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You can drop the `return 0;`.

You should really find a consistent formatting. Since I'm lazy, I just ran it through `clang-format` with the default settings (LLVM-style) except with 4-space tabs.

It's probably best not to call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` - there's no real reason to avoid flushing unless you are actually needing the speed. I also removed the timing code, since it seems to be for debugging purposes.

This all gives:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct input_rec {
    int fizz;
    int buzz;
    int length;
};

input_rec parseRecord(std::string const &record) {
    std::istringstream stream(record);

    int fizz, buzz, length;
    stream >> fizz >> buzz >> length;
    return {fizz, buzz, length};
}

void checkfizzbuzz(input_rec rec) {
    for (int x = 1; x <= rec.length; ++x) {
        if ((x % rec.fizz) == 0 && (x % rec.buzz) == 0) {
            std::cout << "FB";
        } else if ((x % rec.fizz) == 0) {
            std::cout << "F";
        } else if ((x % rec.buzz) == 0) {
            std::cout << "B";
        } else {
            std::cout << x;
        }

        if (x < rec.length) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "usage: fuuzbuzz fuuzbuzz.txt" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    std::string record;

    while (std::getline(infile, record)) {
        checkfizzbuzz(parseRecord(record));
    }
}
```

Note that there's basically no *real* error checking in this, which is worth fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from the top…

---

The `input_rec` fields should be more meaningfully named. I suggest `fizz` and `buzz`. It would also be acceptable to use `x`, `y`, and `n`, in accordance with the notation in the challenge.

```
struct input_rec {
    int fizz;
    int buzz;
    int last;
};
```

---

The parsing in `parseRecord()` would be much simpler using a `std::stringstream`. It is generally assumed that you don't need to validate the inputs in these kinds of problems; the given limits just tell you how scalable your solution needs to be. In any case, your validation is ineffective because you don't have a Plan B when the input is invalid. Furthermore, your `good` variable is pointless — it's always `1` if it reaches the end.

I suggest taking a `std::istream` instead of a `std::string` to help simplify code elsewhere.

```
bool parseRecord(std::istream &input, input_rec& rec)
{
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(input, line))
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    return ss >> rec.fizz >> rec.buzz >> rec.last;
}
```

---

I personally wouldn't bother with `readInputFile()`, since you can just process one line at a time instead of parsing all of the input before printing all of the output. If you do write a `readInputFile`, I suggest accepting a `std::istream&` instead of a filename, so that the function could also work with `std::cin`.

---

The `checkfuzzbuzz` function is weirdly named — what is it checking? And why `fuzzbuzz` instead of `fizzbuzz`? (Nor is it "fuuzbuzz", as you wrote in `main()`.) The `rec` should be `const`.

You have a **huge block of copy-pasted code** which is unjustified. The only difference is the delimiter character — so make a conditional for just that little difference. (Can you spot a copy-paste bug in your code?)

Note that the looping and the use of variables could be vastly improved as well.

```
void fizzbuzz(const input_rec& rec)
{    
    for (int n = 1; n <= rec.last; ++n)
    {
        bool fizz = (n % rec.fizz == 0);
        bool buzz = (n % rec.buzz == 0);

        if (fizz && buzz)
        {
            std::cout << "FB";           
        }
        else if (fizz)
        {
            std::cout << "F";
        }   
        else if (buzz)
        {
            std::cout << "B";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << n;
        }
        std::cout << (n == rec.last) ? '\n' : ' ';
    }
}
```

---

If the command-line parameters are invalid, print the error message to `std::cerr` (not `std::cout`) and exit with a non-zero status.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: fizzbuzz fuuzbuzz.txt\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    input_rec input;
    while (parseRecord(infile, input))
    {
       fizzbuzz(input);
    }
    auto end      = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
    std::cerr << duration.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Timing output should also go to standard error, not standard output.